# Vue JS what does # do inside a <template> does in v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to vue js, i was given an project example to study, i want to ask what <template #['item.amtv_start_sales_date'] = "{item}'> actually do inside . Any help is appreciated thanks

```html
   <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="data" :search="search">
              <template #[`item.amtv_start_sales_date`]="{ item }">
                <div
                  :class="
                    checkDateActiveColorSales(
                      item.amtv_start_sales_date,
                      item.amtv_end_sales_date
                    )
                  "
                  @click="click(item.amtv_start_sales_date)"
                  style="font-weight: 500"
                >
                  {{ item.amtv_start_sales_date }}
                </div>
            </v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots)

> `v-slot` has a dedicated shorthand `#`, so `<template v-slot:header>` can be shortened to just `<template #header>`. Think of it as "render this template fragment in the child component's 'header' slot"
> [image: vue]

So `` <template #[`item.amtv_start_sales_date`]="{ item }"> `` is originally written as `` <template v-slot[`item.amtv_start_sales_date`]="{ item }"> ``